# (this) + Arrow Function in JavaScript () =>

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I have some struggle to understand how the arrow functions in JS actually work.

Please consider this snippet

```
  editButton.onclick = () => this.edit(input);

    edit(input){
        input.disabled = !input.disabled;
    }
```

Why does that work but this here not?

```
  editButton.onclick = function() {
            this.edit(input);
        }
    }

    edit(input){
        input.disabled = !input.disabled;
    }
```

Not the same? If I replace `this.edit(input)` with `console.log("Test");` it works on both but `this.edit(input)` somehow not, why is that so?
I mean `() =>`is basically `function() { }`no??

Comment: because the "this" object has no more the same meaning

Comment: the "this" has not the same meaning in arrow functions or in normal functions

Comment: Obviously, `this.edit` is a property of a class or constructor, so within an arrow function it scopes up to the constructor. `this` within an EventListener, assigned a normal function, scopes to the Element.